# FaceBook Graph API Call to like a page

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Can I like the facebook page from my iPhone App using Graph API call? If yes ..Please tell me the URL for the API call.

Answer (score 0):

The url actually `https://graph.facebook.com/`, you can use this tool `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` for testing.

P.S. the page `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#graph` is also useful I suppose.

Comment: Can any one point me the Graph API Call to like a facebook page? I need solution for this immediatley..Thanks in advance..